# Typescript what is the difference between a genic written before a function or after a type declaration?

Tags: typescript

What is the difference between the two type declaration for arrow function?

```
export type Sort = <D>(r: Rows<D>, f: Field<D>, o: Order) => Rows<D>;
```

```
export type Sort<D> = (r: Rows<D>, f: Field<D>, o: Order) => Rows<D>;
```

Comment: In first case, you allow TypeScript to infer `D` type from function arguments. In second example, you should manually provide `D` generic type if you want to use `Sort` type. You can take a look at my article https://catchts.com/infer-arguments for more context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functional wise there is none difference, TS compiler will enforce you to declare D in a different place:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-yb3pjn?file=index.ts

```
interface Foo {
 valX: number
}

interface Bar {
 valY: string
}

interface Rows<D> {
 rows: D[]
}

interface Field<D> {
  value: D
}

type Order = 'asc' | 'desc'

export type SortA = <D>(r: Rows<D>, f: Field<D>, o: Order) => Rows<D>;
export type SortB<D> = (r: Rows<D>, f: Field<D>, o: Order) => Rows<D>;

const sortFunction: SortA = <Foo>(rows: Rows<Foo>, field: Field<Foo>, o: Order) => {
  return rows
}

const sortBFunction: SortB<Bar> = (rows: Rows<Bar>, field: Field<Bar>, o: Order) => {
  return rows
}
```

Comment: You can omit explicit argument types on both function if you are using explicit function type. See playground: tsplay.dev/NVK6vm